# How to only use one argument when a tuple of two is returned

Tags: python

The function `os.path.split` for example return a tuple of head and tail.
I must specify both parts of the tuple but if I only need one of them pylint complains about an unused parameter. What is the proper way to do this in python?

```
(head, tail) = os.path.split("a/b/c")
```

Comment: If you need only `head`, try `head, _` or if you need only `tail`, use `_, tail`.

Comment: `head = os.path.split("a/b/c")[0]` also works. Not as slick looking, but it avoids making an unnecessary binding.

Comment: For what it's worth: since [Python 3.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/), you can do e.g. `a, *_ = "a/b/c".split('/')` to skip multiple parts (and, vice versa, `*_, c = "a/b/c".split('/')`; but (obviously) *not* `*_, b, *_ = "a/b/c".split('/')`).

Comment: @JohnColeman Assumes an indexable iterable (probably reasonable here)- or else `next(iter(iterable))` would be an alternative

Comment: @Chris_Rands Good point, though OP did specify tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to use `_`.

For example:

`head, _ = os.path.split("a/b/c")`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `_`:

```
head, _ = os.path.split("a/b/c")
```

This is a convention that most IDEs use to interpret that the programmer is not interested in that value, however, the `_` is a legal variable name and will point to the value being "ignored":

```
>>> x = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> _, *middle, _ = x
>>> _
4
```

You can even use something like this if you are having more than two values:

```
>>> x = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> x
(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> first, *middle, last = x
>>> first
1
>>> middle
[2, 3]
>>> last
4
```

Therefore, you can still use `_` to "ignore" some parts of a pattern, like so:

```
>>> x = (1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> x
(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> _, *middle, _ = x
>>> middle
[2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

use the underscore to indicate that a variable is expected but you do't want to use it.

For example use:

```
   head, _ = os.path.split("a/b/c")
```